Does 'either-or' mean 'at least one of'?

Find the probability that a leap year selected at random will contain either $53$ Thursdays or $53$ Fridays.

My Attempt:
Last two days can be
(i) Sunday, Monday
(ii) Monday, Tuesday
(iii) Tuesday, Wednesday
(iv) Wednesday, Thursday
(v) Thursday, Friday
(vi) Friday, Saturday
(vii) Saturday, Sunday
Now, whether to pick option (iv) and (vi) or (v) as well?
Say, I am at a drinks party, and I am asked what I would have and I say either tea or coffee. That doesn't mean I could be given both tea and coffee as well.
So, I wonder why the given answer is 3/7, instead of 2/7.

Regardless of how the question is interpreted, the answer will have a denominator of $97$, not $7$. There are $97$ leap years in a Gregorian cycle, a prime number. I don't know offhand how many of them begin on each day of the week.

If I counted right, of the $97$ leap years in a Gregorian cycle there are $14$ that start on a Wednesday, $13$ that start on a Thursday, and $15$ that start on a Friday; so your probability is $\frac{29}{97}$ with the exclusive interpretation, $\frac{42}{97}$ with the inclusive interpretation.

To follow up on the point made by @MauroALLEGRANZA, since we are talking about alternatives, then they cannot both occur. Properly used, "either $x$ or $y$" means the same as "$x$ or $y,$ but not both." However, it is an extremely common usage error to use "either" as a throwaway word to introduce a list of choices, even when the choices are not mutually exclusive. TL;DR: check with the source whenever possible to find out which is meant, but it should indicate exclusive choices (when used correctly).

People at a party rarely hold two drinks for themselves at the same time, but years have at least 52 of each day of the week and leap years invariably have 53 of two different days of the week. A leap year that has 53 Thursdays and does not have 53 Fridays must therefore have 53 Wednesdays. This is like being at a party and saying you want either tea or coffee, then someone hands you a cup of tea and a glass of beer. The analogy doesn't hold water (or tea, or coffee).

@CameronBuie A number of sources seem to take the prescriptive viewpoint that "either" precludes "both," but the "error" of using "either" in a non-exclusive sense is so common that one really can't rely on the prescriptive meaning. Hence one can find many sets of logic course notes that say a proposition is a statement that is "either true or false, but not both." And there's evidence that the LSAT writers, or at least some LSAT coaches, use "either" inclusively: https://blog.powerscore.com/lsat/bid-268836-when-does-either-or-mean-both-on-the-lsat/.

@DavidK I have posted an answer, please check.

There is Gregorian calender that includes 97 leap year cycle that means that every 98th leap year will be same to first leap year. There are 14 that start with Wednesday which will contain 53 Wednesday and 53 Thursdays. There will be 15 that start with Friday containing 53 Fridays and 53 Saturdays. Here we won't take starting with Thursday as it will contain both 53 Thursdays and 53 Fridays. Therefore the probability of getting either 53 Thursdays or 53 fridays is (15+14)/97 which is 29/97. Therefore the probability is 29/97.

This answer picks up correctly on the actual logical flaw in the original question, namely the assumption about equal distribution of the first weekday of a leap year. But it doesn't explain the resolution of the ambiguous "either" at all.

In case of disjoint sets, either-or won't include both.
e.g. if I am asking for either a single digit number or a $4$ digits number then I would be given only one of these.
But if I am asking for a prime number or an odd number then I can be given $3$ or $5$ or $17$.
i.e. in case of overlapping sets, either-or can include both.
Talking about real life example,
Either tea or coffee won't mean both. But a blue shirt or a cotton shirt can include a blue cotton shirt.
Coming to the original question, I think we need to include the case involving both $53$ Thursdays and $53$ Fridays.
